# Memory leak with web worker + canvas

Tags: javascript, memory, canvas, html5-canvas, rendering

I am attempting to migrate some of the drawing logic for a waterfall spectrum graph to a web worker because it was causing jitter with other, less graphics-intense graphs on the page. In the new model, the canvas control is transferred to the web worker and instructions with data to draw are regularly sent, rather than all the drawing taking place directly on the main thread.

I have noticed that a significant memory leak occurs and eventually slows the page to a halt  (after approx. 10 seconds). I have isolated it to the worker using Chrome's memory tools, and I was able to isolate it to the call to `fillRect(...)`. I do not understand why this occurs because there is no memory leak when using the same function on the main thread. The only way to alleviate this issue, I found, was calling `delete data[i]` after `fillRect`. This was not a permanent fix, however, and I still saw that some memory leaked and jitter occurred.

waterfall.tsx

```
let Waterfall = (...) => {  // react component - worker and time received as props

  ...

  useEffect(() => {  // time-controlled

    let workerRequest: {
      data: FFTSample[], 
      lineWidth: number, 
      lineHeight: number, 
      dy?: number
    }[] = [];

    // data: array of server messages containing fft information for one point in time
    for (const sample of data) {
      if (sample.time < minTime) {
        // skip frames that run off screen
        continue;
      }

      if ((sample.time - lastTime) > TIME_BETWEEN_LINES) {  // sync with desired number of frames
        let dy = y(sample.time);
        let offset = dy - (lastDy + LINE_HEIGHT);  // compensate for jitters in the time math calculation

        if (dy <= 0 && sample.time != minTime) {
          // if frame moves all the way off screen, record its time
          // this is used to sync samples that are displayed across renders,
          // since not all frames are displayed
          setMinTime(sample.time);
        }

        lastTime = sample.time;
        lastDy = dy;

        // add row, with compensations applied
        workerRequest.push({
          data: sample.payload,
          lineWidth: width,
          lineHeight: (LINE_HEIGHT + 0.5) + offset,
          dy: (dy - LINE_HEIGHT) - offset
        });
      }
    }

    worker.postMessage({ draw: workerRequest });

  }, [time]);

  ...

}
```

worker.ts

```
import { FFTSample } from "../typings";
import * as d3 from "d3";

let paintWaterfallRow = (
  ctx: OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D, data: FFTSample[], lineWidth: number, lineHeight: number, 
  z: d3.ScaleSequential<string>, dy?: number
) => {
  let chunkWidth = Math.ceil(lineWidth / data.length) + 1;
  dy = dy || 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let point = data[i];
    let color = z(point.magnitude);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect((i / data.length) * lineWidth, dy, chunkWidth, lineHeight);
  }
}

let canvas: OffscreenCanvas;
let context: OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D;
let zScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis);

self.onmessage = (msg: MessageEvent) => {
  let data = msg.data;

  // store canvas
  if ("canvas" in data) {
    canvas = data.canvas;
    context = canvas.getContext("2d")!;
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    if ("scale" in data) {
      context.scale(data.scale, data.scale);
    }
    console.log("worker: canvas set")
  }
  
  // store domain details for z scale (color information)
  if ("z" in data) {
    let zDomain = data.z;
    zScale.domain([zDomain[0], zDomain[1]]);
    console.log("worker: z-scale set");
  }

  // draw chart
  if ("draw" in data) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (const line of data.draw) {
      paintWaterfallRow(
        context,
        line.data,  // FFTSample[]
        line.lineWidth,
        line.lineHeight,
        zScale,
        line.dy
      );
    }
  }
}
```

How can I better understand this issue?

Comment: At what frequency do you send new messages to the worker? Also, you might improve perfs by "a lot", if you do gather all the same colored rects and draw them in a single path using `rect()` and a single `fill()` per color. But I doubt that affects your memory issue.

Comment: @Kaiido I agree that doesn't affect the memory issue. The send rate is quite high, at this point about 30 times a second, because it's real-time rendering.

Comment: @Kaiido To your first point - I tried this but I was getting results that were less than precise so I abandoned it. I know that doesn't really make sense but I couldn't figure it out. I will note I am still relatively inexperienced with canvas as a whole.

Comment: Please show how you do post new messages to the worker. And I don't see why there would be a precision loss from fillRect() to `rect()` + `fill()`. Please also show what you tried on that.

Comment: @Kaiido Edited to show how the messages are being posted. I asked a separate question regarding the other error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77809509/9717184

Comment: I'm really not into react so I'm not sure how your "time-controlled" `useEffect` is supposed to work, but are you 100% confident it's not ran too often? If your component sends data faster than your worker can process it, you'll be accumulating a lot of queued messages, all containing seemingly big objects to clone. You could set up a flag based system, where your main thread would wait for the worker tells it it's done handling the previous message, and not send more data until that flag is raised.

Comment: @Kaiido It is ran quite often. I couldn't find information on the upper bounds of what workers could handle in terms of data received. The flag system is not feasible because the point of the worker, in theory, was to eliminate jitter and allow to the canvas to work at 60fps undisturbed by the main thread. Perhaps it would be better to rework the data structure to be transferrable to improve performance.

Comment: What does quite often mean? There is no upper bound to the drawings on a canvas. However a placholder `<canvas>` will only get updated every painting frames.The flag system wouldn't prevent working at 60 FPS on the contrary. There is no reason to produce more frames than what the monitor can render anyway.

Comment: @Kaiido I am 100% confident the component effect runs at a maximum 60 times per second (if anything, it may run slightly less than that). I struggle to understand how a flag system which buffers the amount of data sent to reduce load will prevent jitter - if the worker is overloaded with the amount of messages incoming, pausing the data flow should cause a noticeable rendering pause, should it not? (Also - by "upper bound", I was referring to how much data will cause a worker to become overloaded.)

Comment: The idea of the flag is that in case there is too much data being sent to the Worker, which would cause data being queued in the Worker's message queue, the main thread would not send any new data before the worker is finally ready to handle it. So yes, you may lose one or two frames now and then, but it's certainly better than being late by at least the same amount of frames and even worst, being overloaded and having a slow or crashing app entirely.