# Canvas: fillRect x-coordinate jitter when drawn quickly

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, rendering

I am creating a waterfall-style spectrogram that moves vertically as live radio data is received. I am attempting to migrate to a more efficient method of drawing the color graph; by collecting coordinate positions for each color, so that the canvas fill style is modified less times. The result is much more efficient, but it is creating an odd inaccuracy in the results (screenshots below).

A minified example of both methods are below:

```
// Method 1 - less efficient

let paintWaterfallRow = (
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, data: FFTSample[], lineWidth: number, lineHeight: number, 
  z: d3.ScaleSequential<string>, dy?: number
) => {
  let chunkWidth = Math.ceil(lineWidth / data.length) + 1;
  dy = dy || 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let point = data[i];
    let color = z(point.magnitude);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect((i / data.length) * lineWidth, dy, chunkWidth, lineHeight);
  }
}

for (const sample of data) {

  ...

  if ((sample.time - lastTime) > TIME_BETWEEN_LINES) {  // sync with desired number of frames
    let dy = y(sample.time);
    let offset = dy - (lastDy + LINE_HEIGHT);  // compensate for jitters in the time math calculation

    ...

    paintWaterfallRow(ctx, sample.payload, width, (LINE_HEIGHT + 0.5) + offset, zScale.scale, (dy - LINE_HEIGHT) - offset);

    lastTime = sample.time;
    lastDy = dy;
  }
}
```

```
// Method 2 - more efficient

let posData: {
  [_: string]: {
    x: number,
    y: number,
    height: number
  }[]
} = {};

for (const sample of data) {
  
  ...

  if ((sample.time - lastTime) > TIME_BETWEEN_LINES) {  // sync with desired number of frames
    let dy = y(sample.time);
    let offset = dy - (lastDy + LINE_HEIGHT);  // compensate for jitters in the time math calculation

    ...

    // collect position data

    let payload = sample.payload;
    for (let i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
      let samplePoint = payload[i];
      let color = zScale.scale(samplePoint.magnitude);

      if (!posData.hasOwnProperty(color))
        posData[color] = [];

      posData[color].push({
        x: (i / payload.length) * width,
        y: (dy - LINE_HEIGHT) - offset,
        height: (LINE_HEIGHT + 0.5) + offset
      })
    }

    lastTime = sample.time;
    lastDy = dy;
  }
}

// draw collected points

const chunkWidth = Math.ceil(width / sample.payload.length) + 1;

for (const [color, points] of Object.entries(posData)) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    let point = points[i];
    ctx.fillRect(point.x, point.y, chunkWidth, point.height);
  }
}
```

The results of method 1 are clear and straight lines:

[image]

However, method two creates x coordinates that randomly move slightly

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I am positive that the length of each sample data line remains the same (64), and adding all x coordinates to a unique set using method 2 yields consistent x coordinates (the set length remains 64, meaning there is no jitter in the math between lines).

Comment: I didn't try to decipher what went wrong in your rewrite, but you could have simply rewritten the first solution by feeding your object with the actual arguments you passed to `fillRect()` and then just do `for (const [color, points] of Object.entries(posData)) { ctx.beginPath(); ctx.fillStyle = color; for (cons args of points) { ctx.rect(...args); } ctx.fill(); }`

Comment: @Kaiido I took this suggestion and modified the `paintWaterfallRow` method to directly add the prepared arguments to an array. The result, for some reason, is the same, with the x-coordinate jitter still observed. Very puzzling. (As a side note, for some reason, using `beginPath()` + `rect(...)` + `fill()` is causing huge page performance hits compared to `fillRect()`, which I don't understand either. And I double checked that all the calls were in the correct scope.)

Comment: I'd need a live [MCVE] to be able to help properly here.

Comment: @Kaiido It will be difficult to minimally reproduce this due to the scope and the fact that it is connected to a mock server providing the data. The best method may be for me to upload to a repository and share the link.

Comment: @Kaiido Update - I believe I understand the issue. When switching to the different drawing method, the data is drawn by color instead of in a linear pattern. It's actually exposing limitations in my algorithm for sizing each of the color pixels. Since the color pattern can be drawn in a different order every time, different pieces overlap on different frames. What I'm now doing is revising the spacing math to hopefully fix this.